# Parametrize JUnit test in Gradle build

Tags: jenkins, gradle, junit

I need to inject some paths and URLs to Gradle managed JUnit tests (like APK file path on remote host and Appium server URL) because local environment differ from CI and there are several CI envs...

How can I inject settings into tests (as strings)? I see the use of `Sysyem.getenv()` included in `static` blocks to bypass Gradle smartness. I can set variables before calling Gradle:

```
USE_SERVER=http://mobi-tester.local  gradle testServerApiOnAndroid
```

I don't see the way to get it works with system properties, unless use something like:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    systemProperties System.properties
    // or
    systemProperty "myvariable", System.getProperty("myvariable")
}
```

Is there any declarative way to inject strings into variables with pure JUnit?

Please, don't suggest https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests - you just haven't got the question right ((

Comment: I missed initially that you want to use system properties by some reason. Why environment variables do not work for you? Just use `System.getenv("USE_SERVER")` as a way to access the setting in test and that would be enough.

Comment: I thought that fancy frameworks like JUnit should have some declarative syntax for passing configurations. I don't mind to use env var